# Combining the Select and Input box in a row with Boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I combine all the form group items such as Select, Input items together just using bootstrap framework?

I have tried the below way but as expected I am getting the space between Select and Input Box

[**DEMO**](https://www.bootply.com/ZroH4GboPy)

Comment: What do you mean "combine all the form group items... together"? Are you wanting to send them to the server together or group them together on the page?

Comment: No In the UI I wanted to Combine them together..using boostrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your declaration of `mx-sm-3`.  This applies for the `-sm` breakpoint *and greater* if there is no other declaration.  The simplest way to correct this is add a reset at the larger breakpoint: `mx-md-0`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="custom-select mx-md-0">
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mx-md-0">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mx-md-0">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expand the above code snippet to see how it will render when you exceed the `-sm` breakpoint.  I also changed your `<select>` to make use of the `custom-select` class.

Comment: Thanks I wanted to this way !!

Comment: where can I get the custom-select class definition

Comment: `.custom-select` is part of Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-forms

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but if it's not, clarify what you're after a little more and I might be able to help.

If you're just wanting to group the items together, bootstrap has a `card` class that allows you to group elements into a container of sorts. The code below is wrapped in bootstraps grid system. I've put your code into a `div` tag with a `card` class. In a second example, I've removed a the `inline` form class, so you can see how the inputs are stacked vertically.

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                <option>One</option>
                                <option>Two</option>
                                <option>Three</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                <option>One</option>
                                <option>Two</option>
                                <option>Three</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/r4nQlm6q1n) so you can see how the layout.

Comment: Thanks @cwanjt tough I didnt want this way but your approach will help me to make the login form looks good Hence Upvoted!!